# Server Side Rendering - ReactDOMServer.renderToString returns empty routes html (router 4)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4, server-rendering

I'm trying to render react application on server, but it seems that renderToString function doesn't render routes html only header and footer. By looking at the code of the page you can see only the header and footer that the server returned from App.js. But the code that is in the routes is not on the page.

I'm using React-Router v4. My code looks like this:

server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import {StaticRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import createMemoryHistory from 'history/createMemoryHistory';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { ConnectedRouter, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import { multiClientMiddleware } from 'redux-axios-middleware';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import api from "../src/actions/api";
import rootReducer from "../src/reducers/index";
import routes from '../src/routes/routes';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import Helmet from "react-helmet";
import render from './render';

const app = express();

global.navigator = { userAgent: 'all' };
app.use(express.static('assets'));

app.get('*', (req,res)=>{
const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
const axiosMiddlewareOptions = {};
const history = createMemoryHistory();
const appRouterMiddleware = routerMiddleware(history);
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(multiClientMiddleware(api, axiosMiddlewareOptions), appRouterMiddleware)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer);

const context = {};

const appWithRouter = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
            <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
                <ConnectedRouter history={history} children={routes}/>
            </StaticRouter>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    </Provider>
);

if (context.url) {
    res.redirect(context.url);
    return
}

const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(appWithRouter);

res.status(200).send(render(html, helmet))
});

app.listen(8080, ()=>{
    console.log('Server is Listening')
});
```

render.js

```
export default (html, helmet) => `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ${helmet.htmlAttributes.toString()}>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            ${helmet.title.toString()}
            <base href="/"/>
            <link href="./img/favikin-hw.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
            <link href="./build/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <meta name="viewport" content=" width=device-width, maximum-scale=1">
        </head>

        <body>
            <div class="wrapper">${html}</div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="./build/app.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>

`;
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from "react";
import Header from '../components/Header/Header';
import Footer from '../components/Footer/Footer';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="wrapper-box">
            <div className="inner-wrapper">
                <Header/>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    );
   }
  }

 App.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.object.isRequired
 };

 export default App;
```

roures.js

```
import React from 'react';
import App from '../containers/App';
import {
   Route,
   Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';
import MainPage from '../containers/MainPage/MainPage';
import DetailPage from '../components/DetailPage/DetailPage';
import AboutProject from '../containers/AboutProject/AboutProject';
import Contacts from '../containers/Contacts/Contacts';
import SectionPage from '../containers/SectionPage/SectionPage';
import SearchPage from '../containers/SearchPage/SearchPage';
import NoMatch from '../containers/NoMatch/NoMatch';


export default (
<App>
<div>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact={true} path='/' component={MainPage} />
        <Route path='/about_the_project' component={AboutProject} />
        <Route path='/contacts' component={Contacts} />
        <Route path="/search-results/:category/:term" component={SearchPage}/>
        <Route exact={true} path='/:name' component={SectionPage} />
        <Route path="/articles/:slug" component={DetailPage}/>
        <Route path="/events/:slug" component={DetailPage}/>
        <Route path="/news/:slug" component={DetailPage}/>
        <Route path="/interviews/:slug" component={DetailPage}/>
        <Route path="/technologies/:slug" component={DetailPage}/>
        <Route path='*' component={NoMatch}/>
    </Switch>
</div>
</App>
)
```

client.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { ConnectedRouter, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import { multiClientMiddleware } from 'redux-axios-middleware';
import api from "./actions/api";
import rootReducer from "./reducers/index";
import routes from './routes/routes';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import '../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import '../assets/style.css';
import '../node_modules/react-datetime/css/react-datetime.css';
import '../node_modules/react-select/dist/react-select.min.css';

const axiosMiddlewareOptions = {};

const history = createBrowserHistory();
const appRouterMiddleware = routerMiddleware(history);
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(multiClientMiddleware(api, axiosMiddlewareOptions), appRouterMiddleware)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer, {}, window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f);

render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <MuiThemeProvider>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history} children={routes}/>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
</Provider>,
document.querySelector('.wrapper'));
```

Comment: I think my problem is with the data inside the components, the server displays the code as if there is not where to render it.

Comment: hi. how do you manage to show a detailPage? the technologies/:slug for example?